# Where to find reference of all/common ObjectClasses of ldap using their English names not OID numbers?

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap

I know the following questions could be naive, but I an ldap beginner and tried searching but i didn't find what am looking for exactly

I am trying to get a reference about ldap object classes and their attributes along with description by searching the internet , but in search results object classes and attributes are mapped to a OID  number not their name in plain English  which is confusing me.

- It will be helpful you provide me a link to a reference that uses English names of the object classes and a table of their attributes
  along with description about each but not rfc or OID number .

I tried searching google but i didn't get something organized and comprehensive in English names

- Also another point I have some difficulties understanding the default
  configuration tree, especially the :

  **cn=config** versus **olcDatabase={0}Config**

  **cn=schema** versus **cn={0}core**

  function/use of **olcDatabase={2}hdb**

  function/use of  **olcDatabase={-1}frontend**
- Third and last point for configuration ldif files under slapd.d
  directory, each file contain some directives that begin with olc ,
  for those directives does they describe/configure metadata about the
  database like where they are stored (directory to store database
  files) and how they behave like whether having index ..etc or just
  these directives constitute the actual data stored in the backend
  openldap is communicating with even if they are translated to other
  format before being stored or both .

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: https://ldapwiki.com/ Is pretty good and lists by names.

Comment: @JasonCroyle Thanks for ur comment , i followed the link and found it helpful really by names :D

Comment: I'd suggest to split your questions at least into two question postings. I will answer the first matching the subject for now.

Comment: but i will accept ur answer becuse its related to the main topic of the threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some web sites out there which lists typical schema descriptions. But don't expect them to be complete. It's simply not possible to cover every schema and its vendor-specific variants.

[ldapwiki - LDAP Schema](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20Schema) gives a good introduction also referencing some relevant RFCs.

A brief overview of some RFCs you should look at:

- [RFC 4519 - Schema for User Applications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519)
- [RFC 4524 - COSINE LDAP/X.500 Schema](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4524)
- [RFC 2798 - Definition of the inetOrgPerson LDAP Object Class](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2798)
- [RFC 2307 - An Approach for Using LDAP as a Network Information Service](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2307)

But there are also service-specific schema descriptions for DNS entries and DHCP data.

Also look at [web2ldap](https://web2ldap.de)'s schema viewer. It displays all cross-references for all schema descriptions back and forth. I don't know a more powerful tool to explore the subschema subentry currently installed on an LDAP server, especially for finding out the differences in vendor-specific variants. There's a [demo page](https://web2ldap.de/demo.html) from where you can directly jump into the schema browser accessing public LDAP demo servers. Being the author of web2ldap I'm biased of course.

Comment: Of course that is very clear , I will accept that answer